# Returning Promise from AWS.SWF Workflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

It seems that according to [swf-docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/clients.html) the following code:

```
@Workflow
@WorkflowRegistrationOptions(
   defaultExecutionStartToCloseTimeoutSeconds = 60,
   defaultTaskStartToCloseTimeoutSeconds = 10)
public interface MyWorkflow
{
    @Execute(version = "1.0")
    Promise<String> startMyWF(int a, String b);
}
```

Should generate  `MyWorkflowClientExternal` that returns a `Promise<String>`; i.e.:

```
Promise<String> startMyWF(int a, String b);
```

However, instead a void method is generated for both `MyWorkflowClientExternal` and `MyWorkflowClientExternalImpl`:

```
void startMyWF(int a, String b) ...
```

The internal client `MyWorkflowClient` and `MyWorkflowClientImpl` does return the Promise object as expected:

```
Promise<String> startMyWF(int a, String b);
```

I would like to use `ExternalClient`; but it does not seem to return the `Promise` object.  I would very much appreciate clarifications.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted this [question](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=530115) on the AWS-SWF developer forum; and @maxim-fateev has kindly pointed several approaches:

> The return value of a workflow is very useful for child workflows
>   because they are modeled as asynchronous calls. For standalone
>   workflows, you can use one of the following options to retrieve the
>   results:
>
> 1) Get it from the workflow history using SWF API
>   GetWorkflowExecutionHistory (the result is in the
>   WorkflowExecutionCompleted event). You can also inspect the history
>   using the SWF console.
>
> 2) Design your workflow to put the result somewhere, for example you
>   can add an activity at the end to put the result in a store and have
>   the application look there periodically.
>
> 3) Host an activity in the program that starts the workflow execution.
>   The workflow starter program now becomes part of the workflow and the
>   activity it hosts can be passed the result of the workflow.
>
> You may use the first option in manually operated tools. However, it
>   is not recommended as a general mechanism for applications to retrieve
>   workflow results because it effectively requires you to poll SWF to
>   check for workflow completion and goes against our long polling
>   design.

I went with the approach #2; here is the gist of it (if you think there is a better way; please do let me know).

Created `NotificationActivityImpl`:

```
public class NotificationActivitiesImpl implements NotificationActivities {

    private Object notification;

    public NotificationActivitiesImpl() {
        this.notification = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void notify(Object obj) {
        this.notification = obj;
    }

    /**
     * @return notification (will block until it is available)
     */
    @Override
    public Object getNotification() {
        while (notification == null ){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return notification;
    }
}
```

In the `WorkflowImpl` added:

```
notificationClient.notify(obj) // obj that want to pass back to your app
```

In the App (which starts the workflow; and NotificationAcitivityWorker) added the following:

```
workflowWorker.start();
notificationWorker.start();
NotificationActivitiesImpl notificationImpl = (NotificationActivitiesImpl) notificationWorker.getActivitiesImplementations().iterator().next();
Object notification = notificationImpl.getNotification();
```

Comment: Can you please post some code on how to use this with ExternalClient?